# Display resolution in duplicate monitor

Tags: display

I use duplicate one monitor laptop LCD and other monitor that monitor resolution is bigger than laptop LCD.  How can I set laptop LCD resolution for them?

When I use the mirror button it sets 1024 * 768 but my laptop LCD resolution is 1366 * 768 -- how can I set this resolution for them?  When I set this resolution I get an error. My laptop is an HP dv6 6080 and VGA is Intel sandy bridge if I change to AMD VGA can I resolve this problem?

This is the `xrandr output -q` output.  How can I put laptop resolution for two lcd that full monitors screen?

```
    xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        60.0  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your monitor does not support the wide screen resolution of 1366x768 you will not be able to set that resolution. You can likely set your laptop to use the 1024x768 though.

If it is a wide screen monitor then you should be able to set that resolution in:

system settings > displays

If you do not have that resolution then the system is not identifying the external monitor properly.

Comment: My monitor is wide screen and i use that on win7 properly but i can't use that on ubuntu!!!

Comment: when you go to system settings > displays do you have the option to set the resolution to 1366x768?

Comment: yes i have an option to set 1366*768 but when i set i get error that can't settings this resolution on external monitor!

Comment: what is the manufacturer and model of the monitor?

Comment: samsung syncmaster p22500

Comment: The monitor is capable... is it connected via VGA or DVI?

Comment: It is connected via VGA to my laptop  
When i connect that via VGA on win7 i can set my laptop lcd monitor to that but in ubuntu i can't!

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion, maybe you can use the `xrandr` to fix up the resolution on both monitor. I'm using the Samsung NP148 (Netbook) with onBoard intel graphic accelerator, when I connected to the LCD monitor through the VGA cable, I can fix the resolution using the `xrandr` at ease.

to ensure that the LCD screen connected, you have to run this :

```
xrandr -q
```

this will list all available monitor connected to the laptop and the laptop's monitor itself (LVDS). With `xrandr`, all configuration are in command line and I found that command line sometimes could be a great troublesome. I'm suggesting for you to use the `grandr`, the GUI-version for the `xrandr`. You can install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install grandr
```

Then, run this app. After that, you might able to set the display resolution for both of the monitor. If you are on nVidia-powered box, you can use the `disper` but since you are not on it, feel free to follow guides about. Tell me if it is working~